# .is(focus) vs .activeElement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've run into a strange problem, which I've already resolved using `document.activeElement.id`, but when using `$('#id').is(':focus')` seems to always return `false`.

In my console, I tested out the following...

```
> document.activeElement
<input type="text" for="zoomSlider" id="zoomText" oninput="zoomSliderUpdate(value)" value="100">

> $('#zoomText')
<input type="text" for="zoomSlider" id="zoomText" oninput="zoomSliderUpdate(value)" value="100">

> $('#zoomText').is(':focus')
false

> document.activeElement // to check if focus was lost somehow
<input type="text" for="zoomSlider" id="zoomText" oninput="zoomSliderUpdate(value)" value="100">
```

Why does `is(':focus')` return a false?

Comment: You left out the # in front of zoomText. If you are searching for an element by id in jquery, you need to have the # in front, ie  $('#zoomText')

Comment: Here is a post about this problem, and it's related to jQuery version. I don't if it's your scenario, but can be a clue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956906/focus-selector-not-work

Comment: I'm using jQuery 2.2.x for this node project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have a bug in your code. It should be `$('#zoomText').is(':focus')`.

Second, the element will only be in focus if the cursor is inside it. If your cursor is in the JavaScript console, then it has focus and causes the input to be blurred (out of focus).

Try this in the JavaScript console, and then quickly put your cursor back in the input. After 3 seconds, it will show "true" or "false" in the console to indicate the focus state of the "zoomText" element.

```js
setTimeout(function() { console.log(jQuery('#zoomText').is(':focus')); }, 3000)
```

Comment: You're right about the typo, but it was written correctly in my console.  So why does the vanilla JS recognize the focus even in the console while jquery doesn't?  `document.activeElement.id` still registers `zoomText` while doesn't?  Are they looking for different cues that register as `focus` or `active`?

Comment: `document.activeElement` and the pseudo-selected "`:focus`" element are not exactly the same thing. The browser will fire "focus" and "blur" events as the visible focus enters and leaves the element as you switch to and from the console, other tabs, or other windows. However, the browser will maintain the "actively-focused" state of the document and remember which element was in focus, restoring the visible focus when necessary.

Comment: If you want to look at the focus/blur events in action, copy this to your console while here, and use the comment box as your test subject:
`jQuery('[name="comment"]').on('blur', function() { console.log('blur'); }).on('focus', function() { console.log('focus'); })`

Changing focus will obviously fire the events, but so does going to the console, switching tabs, etc. You'll see it fire "focus" when you return to this tab/window. However, `document.activeElement` will remain the same the entire time.